a shortcut file in QTreeView and QFileSystemModel-Python
I encounter a problem using Qtreeview and QFilesystemModel in Pyqt5 with Python Ver3.12. a shortcut file will be shown as a target folder in the Qtreeview. so if I would like to select this shortcut file through
file_path = self.model.filePath(index) 
file_name = self.model.fileName(index)

the path and name of the linked target folder will be returned instead of a shortcut file xxx.lnk
does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem? many thanks in advance!
I tried with following codes from Copilot Suggestion, but it doesnt work. I guess here self.path(index) returns the target folder instead of the shortcut file as well.
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileSystemModel
from PyQt5.QtCore import QModelIndex, Qt

class CustomFileSystemModel(QFileSystemModel):
    def flags(self, index: QModelIndex) -> Qt.ItemFlags:
        defaultFlags = super().flags(index)

        if index.isValid():
            filePath = self.filePath(index)
            if filePath.endswith('.lnk'):
                # Treat .lnk files as regular files, not as links
                return defaultFlags | Qt.ItemIsFile

        return defaultFlags


Problem solved, just use self.model.setResolveSymlinks(False)

setResolveSymlinks() is not completely appropriate, as shortcuts are not actual symlinks. Also, AFAIK, there's no such Qt.ItemIsFile (it probably is an AI allucination). You should use fileInfo() instead in order to know if the node refers to a shortcut. Can you please clarify what is the actual problem you're facing? Is it that you are able to browse through a lnk that points to a directory? Is it about the node metadata (icon, type, contents)? Please provide more details about your issue so that we can provide an acceptable answer (using comments for that is normally frown upon).
